# An RSS feed shows description in Firefox but content:encoded in ie

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, feed

How can i get it to show content:encoded in all cases, not just internet explorer?

thanks,
Reece

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Firefox is unaware of the RSS extension `content:encoded` ([In Firefox, RSS Feeds using Full Text displays as Excerpt](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10689), apparently unreported in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)).

You could consider switching to an Atom feed: `<content type='xhtml'>' is handled by Firefox.